# How to horizontally center text inside cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, text, cell

I´ve been trying to align horizontally the text inside the left-side cells and I couldn´t make it.

Here is my preambule:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.4cm, right=2.4cm, top=2.4cm, bottom=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=green!3,colframe=green!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{mybox2}{,colback=blue!3!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cancel}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{Propuesta de}} % desired width of left-hand column
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\usepackage{float}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}`
```

And this is the table:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Relación de los contenidos con los objetivos didácticos de la Unidad Didáctica.}
\label{tab:Tabla 1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{XX}
\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline
\textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Contenidos}} & \textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Objetivos Didácticos}} \\
\hline
1. Conceptos matemáticos: qué es una función. Relación con las ecuaciones paramétricas. & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
\begin{itemize}
\item[1.1] Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente funciones de una variable.
\end{itemize} 
\end{minipage}\\

\arrayrulecolor{black}\hline

2. Estudio del Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniforme (MRU) y Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniformemente Acelerado (MRUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
\begin{itemize}
\item[2.1] Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRU.
\item[2.2] Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRUA.
\item[2.3] Manejar un tratamiento escalar y vectorial de las ecuaciones del movimiento.
\end{itemize} 
\end{minipage}\\

\hline

3. Composición de MRU y MRUA. Ejemplos: tiro parabólico, oblicuo, horizontal... &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
\begin{itemize}
\item[3.1] Reconocer el movimiento no circular de un móvil en un plano como la composición de dos movimientos unidimensionales (MRU y MRUA).
\item[3.2] Deducir las expresiones matemáticas de tiempo de vuelo, alcance, altura máxima... a partir de las ecuaciones generales del MRU y MRUA.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\\

\hline

4. Estudio del Movimiento Circular Uniforme (MCU) y Movimiento Circular Uniformemente Acelerado (MCUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
\begin{itemize}
\item[4.1] Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCU.
\item[4.2] Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCUA. Explicar la aceleración en función de sus componentes intrínsecas.
\item[4.3] Relacionar las expresiones angulares con las lineales.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\\

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article}

Comment: What exactly does "align horizontally"  mean here?

Comment: I edited the question with an image of the table. I would like the text to be "centred" in each cell on the left.

Comment: Do you want the text in the left column to be vertically centered or horizontally centered? As it currently is, your question unfortunately is a but ambigugous, since the title mentionsvertical alignment, but the body of the question contains the term horizontal alignment. Please clarify.

Comment: Horizontally centered. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: i suspect you mean vertical not horizontal (ie you want to move the left paragraphs down a bit. you could configure the X columns to use `m` instead of `p` but the `tabularx` is doing nothing useful here you can simply use two minipages side by side for each row, they are vertically centred by default. But please fix your example so it can be tests, make it a small but complete example and remove every package not needed for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an answer that focuses on getting the positioning of the blocks in the left-hand and right-hand columns right and tries to reduce visual distractions such as unnecessary or insufficiently-spaced horizontal lines. It works by using the `enumitem` package to set up two bespoke enumerate-like environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referencias}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure} % 'subfigure' is deprecated; don't use it
%%\usepackage{cite} %% load either 'cite' or 'natbib', but not both
\usepackage{pifont}
%%\usepackage{enumerate} % 'enumitem' is more capable than 'enumerate'; see below

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=green!3,colframe=green!75!black}
\newtcolorbox{mybox2}{,colback=blue!3!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%%\usepackage{graphicx} % don't load packages more than one
%\newlength\mylen
%\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{Propuesta de}} % desired width of left-hand column

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{float}
%%\usepackage{color, colortbl} % redundant

\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{mycounter}[table] % reset counter automatically for each 'table' env.
\newlist{myenumA}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{myenumB}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumA]{label  = \themycounter., leftmargin=*, nosep,
                  before = {\stepcounter{mycounter}\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
                  after  = \end{minipage}}
\setlist[myenumB]{label  = \themycounter.\arabic*, leftmargin=*, nosep,
                  before = \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after  = \end{minipage}}

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package _last_

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Relación de los contenidos con los objetivos didácticos de la Unidad Didáctica.}
\label{tab:Tabla 1}

\arrayrulecolor{myGreen} 

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{@{} XX @{}}

\toprule %\hline

\textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Contenidos}} &  \textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Objetivos Didácticos}} \\

\midrule %\hline

\begin{myenumA}
\item Conceptos matemáticos: qué es una función. Relación con las ecuaciones paramétricas. 
\end{myenumA} & 
\begin{myenumB}
\item Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente funciones de una variable.
\end{myenumB} \\


\begin{myenumA}
\item Estudio del Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniforme (MRU) y Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniformemente Acelerado (MRUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. 
\end{myenumA} &
\begin{myenumB}
\item Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRU.
\item Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRUA.
\item Manejar un tratamiento escalar y vectorial de las ecuaciones del movimiento.
\end{myenumB} \\


\begin{myenumA}
\item Composición de MRU y MRUA. Ejemplos: tiro parabólico, oblicuo, horizontal\dots  
\end{myenumA}&
\begin{myenumB}
\item Reconocer el movimiento no circular de un móvil en un plano como la composición de dos movimientos unidimensionales (MRU y MRUA).
\item Deducir las expresiones matemáticas de tiempo de vuelo, alcance, altura máxima\dots a partir de las ecuaciones generales del MRU y MRUA.
\end{myenumB}\\


\begin{myenumA}
\item Estudio del Movimiento Circular Uniforme (MCU) y Movimiento Circular Uniformemente Acelerado (MCUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. 
\end{myenumA}&
\begin{myenumB}
\item  Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCU.
\item Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCUA\@. Explicar la aceleración en función de sus componentes intrínsecas.
\item Relacionar las expresiones angulares con las lineales.
\end{myenumB} \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to vertically align the two blocks on each row on their vertical centres, the `m` column type does this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
% never put a table inside center (it does not center it)
%\begin{center}

\begin{table}% H is not defined by default and best avoided [H]
\caption{Relación de los contenidos con los objetivos didácticos de la Unidad Didáctica.}
\label{tab:Tabla 1}
% no need to use tabularx here
% m gives vertical centering
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{m{0.5\dimexpr\textwidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}}}
\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Contenidos}} & \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Objetivos Didácticos}} \\
\hline
1. Conceptos matemáticos: qué es una función. Relación con las ecuaciones paramétricas. & 
\begin{itemize}
\item[1.1] Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente funciones de una variable.
\end{itemize} 
\\

\arrayrulecolor{black}\hline

2. Estudio del Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniforme (MRU) y Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniformemente Acelerado (MRUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. &
\begin{itemize}
\item[2.1] Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRU.
\item[2.2] Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRUA.
\item[2.3] Manejar un tratamiento escalar y vectorial de las ecuaciones del movimiento
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline

3. Composición de MRU y MRUA. Ejemplos: tiro parabólico, oblicuo, horizontal... &
\begin{itemize}
\item[3.1] Reconocer el movimiento no circular de un móvil en un plano como la composición de dos movimientos unidimensionales (MRU y MRUA).
\item[3.2] Deducir las expresiones matemáticas de tiempo de vuelo, alcance, altura máxima... a partir de las ecuaciones generales del MRU y MRUA.
\end{itemize}
\\

\hline

4. Estudio del Movimiento Circular Uniforme (MCU) y Movimiento Circular Uniformemente Acelerado (MCUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. &
\begin{itemize}
\item[4.1] Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCU.
\item[4.2] Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCUA. Explicar la aceleración en función de sus componentes intrínsecas.
\item[4.3] Relacionar las expresiones angulares con las lineales.
\end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now, as I have the package ragged2e, the text inside the cells are not justified. I tried to use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}         >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X         >{\justifying\arraybackslash\parindent=0pt}X  @{}}` but it didn´t work.

Comment: @DavidMoldes ragged2e does not affect anything by default, text is still justified unless you specify `\RaggedRight` or similar there are almost no circumstances that you ever need `justifying` . But in any case that is a completely different question. Feel free to post a new question, but this time make a small complete document that shows the problem

Comment: @DavidMoldes oh unless you loaded the package with the `[document]` option, in which case not doing that is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant with vertically centered contents in the left column and automated numbering of the individual items using the `enumitem` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=2.4cm, right=2.4cm, top=2.4cm, bottom=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=12pt}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{66FF66}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{009900}

\usepackage{booktabs}    
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label*=\arabic*.,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  nosep,
                  before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                  after=\end{minipage}}
\newlist{contenidos}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenidos]{label*=\arabic*.,
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep,
                     before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                     after=\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{mytabenum}
               {\begin{tabenum}[label*=\thecurrentcontenidos.\arabic*.]}
               {\end{tabenum}}
\newenvironment{mycontenidos}
               [1][resume]
               {\begin{contenidos}[#1=contenidos] }
               {\setcounter{currentcontenidos}{\value{contenidosi}}\end{contenidos}}
               
\newcounter{currentcontenidos}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\caption{Relación de los contenidos con los objetivos didácticos de la Unidad Didáctica.}
\label{tab:Tabla 1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}

\arrayrulecolor{green}
\toprule
\textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Contenidos}} & \textbf{\textcolor{myGreen}{Objetivos Didácticos}} \\
\midrule
\arrayrulecolor{black}

\begin{mycontenidos}[series] % use the optional argument "series"  for the first mycontenidos environment in the table only.
\item Conceptos matemáticos: qué es una función. Relación con las ecuaciones paramétricas. 
\end{mycontenidos} & 

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente funciones de una variable.
\end{mytabenum} 
\\

\midrule
\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Estudio del Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniforme (MRU) y Movimiento Rectilíneo Uniformemente Acelerado (MRUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. 
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRU.
\item Deducir, identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MRUA.
\item Manejar un tratamiento escalar y vectorial de las ecuaciones del movimiento.
\end{mytabenum} 
\\
\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Composición de MRU y MRUA. Ejemplos: tiro parabólico, oblicuo, horizontal... 
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Reconocer el movimiento no circular de un móvil en un plano como la composición de dos movimientos unidimensionales (MRU y MRUA).
\item Deducir las expresiones matemáticas de tiempo de vuelo, alcance, altura máxima... a partir de las ecuaciones generales del MRU y MRUA.
\end{mytabenum}
\\

\midrule

\begin{mycontenidos}
\item Estudio del Movimiento Circular Uniforme (MCU) y Movimiento Circular Uniformemente Acelerado (MCUA). Ecuaciones y gráficas. 
\end{mycontenidos}&

\begin{mytabenum}
\item Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCU.
\item Deducir, Identificar, emplear e interpretar gráficamente las ecuaciones del MCUA. Explicar la aceleración en función de sus componentes intrínsecas.
\item Relacionar las expresiones angulares con las lineales.
\end{mytabenum}
\\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```